# How to make a numpy histogram contain the right bin edge rather than the left bin edge?

Tags: numpy, histogram

By default the bins in numpy.histogram work by including the left bin edge and not the right bin edge. For example:
`array = np.array([1,1,1])` 
`np.histogram(array, bins = np.arange(0,3))`
 outputs: 
`(array([0, 3], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2]))`
Is there a way I can make the histogram include the right bin edge and not the left bin edge? So that the output of the above input becomes: 
`(array([3, 0], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2]))`

Thanks for your help!